# how change array with in array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

i use array and get one dimensional as shown below

```
 a=[(2, 1, [[0, 3]]), (5, 2, [[0, 2], [2, 3]]), (8,    3, [[0, 0], [2, 1], [3, 2]]), (10, 1, [[1, 3]]), (12, 4, [[0, 1], [1, 0], [2, 2], [3, 0]]), (15, 3, [[1, 1], [2, 0], [3, 1]])]
```

how can change it to two dimensional

```
b=[(2, 1, [[0, 3]])
(5, 2, [[0, 2], [2, 3]])
(8, 3, [[0, 0], [2, 1],[3, 2]]),
(12, 4, [[0, 1], [1, 0], [2, 2], [3, 0]])]
```

then convert to another way like

```
c=[(2, 1, 03),(5, 2, 02, 23),(8, 3, 00, 21, 32),(12, 4, 01, 10, 22, 30)]
```

Comment: There may be one too many misunderstandings being conveyed in this post. You should probably take a step back and do a little more reading on the libraries (and language) you're using.

Comment: Looks like you have lists and tuples, but no `numpy` arrays.  There's nothing 1d or 2d about any of the displays, just varying degrees of list nesting.  Items ike `03` are ambiguous.

Comment: Show us what you have written so far. Possibly you are suggesting a problem best solved with recursion, but so far it's not at all clear. Consider using `pprint()` to display arrays: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I copy-n-paste your `a`:

```
In [899]: a=[(2, 1, [[0, 3]]), (5, 2, [[0, 2], [2, 3]]), (8,    3, [[0, 0], [2, 
     ...: 1], [3, 2]]), (10, 1, [[1, 3]]), (12, 4, [[0, 1], [1, 0], [2, 2], [3, 
     ...: 0]]), (15, 3, [[1, 1], [2, 0], [3, 1]])]
```

`ipython` pretty prints it as:

```
In [900]: a                                                                     
Out[900]: 
[(2, 1, [[0, 3]]),
 (5, 2, [[0, 2], [2, 3]]),
 (8, 3, [[0, 0], [2, 1], [3, 2]]),
 (10, 1, [[1, 3]]),
 (12, 4, [[0, 1], [1, 0], [2, 2], [3, 0]]),
 (15, 3, [[1, 1], [2, 0], [3, 1]])]
```

The plain python interpreter might display it the same way, but that's just a display issue, not a data structure one.

If I define a function that takes one of the inner tuples and returns a combination of the 2 values:

```
In [901]: def comb(alist): 
     ...:     return str(alist[0])+str(alist[1]) 
     ...:
```

I can apply it to your list with this list comprehension:

```
In [903]: [(i,j,*[comb(x) for x in k]) for i,j,k in a]                          
Out[903]: 
[(2, 1, '03'),
 (5, 2, '02', '23'),
 (8, 3, '00', '21', '32'),
 (10, 1, '13'),
 (12, 4, '01', '10', '22', '30'),
 (15, 3, '11', '20', '31')]
```

You could write your own `comb` function.  This seems to be the closest to your `c`, except for the quote marks.  But there's no way of producing a `03` except to make it a string.